# VB.net custom button control doesn't work properly

Tags: vb.net, button, controls

I am trying to create a custom button control in VB.Net so that I can add my own text field to it and position it where I want to. But when I do the button no longer acts like a button. None of my addHandlers work and when I click the button, nothing happens. But it does show my text properly. It just loses all of it functionality as a button.

```
Public Class myButton
  Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button
  Public myText As New Label

  Public Sub New(TextString)
        myText.Text = TextString
        myText.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
        myText.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
        Me.Controls.Add(myText)
  End Sub

End Class
```

What am i missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom control you have added a label which is now on top of the button. So you are clicking on label control, not in Button. Please try below snippet which is working for me

```
Public Class myButton
Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Button

Public myText As New Label

Public Event OnButtonClick As EventHandler

Public Sub New(TextString As String)
    myText.Text = TextString
    myText.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    myText.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
    AddHandler myText.Click, AddressOf OnLabelClick
    Me.Controls.Add(myText)
End Sub

Private Sub OnLabelClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    RaiseEvent OnButtonClick(Me, e)
End Sub
End Class
```

**On Form load**

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim customButton As New myButton("vimal")
    AddHandler customButton.OnButtonClick, AddressOf OnCustomButtonClick
    Me.Controls.Add(customButton)
End Sub
Private Sub OnCustomButtonClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    MsgBox("Clicked")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are running into is that the label is getting displayed over your button. Labels have their own action handlers for click events, so when you are clicking the 'button' you are really clicking on the label.